# HTML5 setDragImage(): dragIcon.width does absolutely nothing

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

When using the HTML5 drag and drop API, it would appears though the `.width` property on has no impact on the width of an image being used as an icon for dragging. Take this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/cnAHv/7/. You can set `dragIcon.width` to anything you want, and it will not change the actual width of the icon.

Most of the resources on the web seem to arbitrarily set `dragIcon.width` to 100. Is this just a matter of people copying eachother's code without checking functionality?

So...

1. Is the width property on an image variable actually something that setDragImage() will accept?
2. If not, how would you set the width of the icon without manually changing sizing the image in a program like photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use an `<img>` in `setDragImage` Javascript will just use the actual image bitmap data, ignoring other attributes like `width`. [Check the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/dnd.html#dom-datatransfer-setdragimage).

However if you do something like this:

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
    var dragIcon = document.createElement('img');
    dragIcon.src = 'http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png';
    dragIcon.width = '100';
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(dragIcon);
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(div, -10, -10);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnAHv/9/

You will see the drag shadow now contains the bigger image. It occurs because when we use other visible HTML elements  (that's why I appended the DIV to the body), the browser will use its rendered view as a drag image.

Comment: This places an image in the document and breaks the layout. Are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: Might want to try the last solution in the this blog [link](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html)

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be a bit late but you can also use a canvas to scale your original image.

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
    var dragIcon = document.createElement('img');
    dragIcon.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
    var width = 100;
    var height = width * (3/4); // The height must be set explicitly. I'm assuming the image is 4:3 for this example
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width = width;
    c.height = height;
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(dragIcon,0,0,width,height);
    dragIcon.src = c.toDataURL();
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragIcon, -10, -10);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnAHv/138/

The only downside to this is that the canvas may be tainted if the image doesn't come from the same origin. More on tainted canvases [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)